# App crashes because custom view

Tags: android, android-drawable

I have simple custom view that should draw scaling numbers for progressbar and when i add it to layout it causes crash of app.

```
public class ScaleBar extends View {

    Paint linePaint = new Paint();

    public ScaleBar(Context context) {
        super(context);
        initDrawingTool();
    }

    private void initDrawingTool(){

        linePaint.setColor(Color.WHITE);
    }

    @Override
public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    int skaicius = 9;
    int barHeight = VerticalProgressBar.getVariable();
    for(int i = barHeight/10; i < barHeight-barHeight/10 ; i+=barHeight/10){
        String testString = Integer.toString(skaicius);
        canvas.drawText(testString, getWidth()/2-3, i, linePaint);
        skaicius--;
    }
        canvas.drawText("10", getWidth()/2-10, 20, linePaint);
        canvas.drawText("0", getWidth()/2-3, barHeight, linePaint); 
    }
}
```

Layout XML:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <View.VerticalProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/verticalRatingBar1"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:progress="10"
        android:progressDrawable="@drawable/bluebar" />

    <View.ScaleBar
        android:id="@+id/scaling"
        android:layout_width="30dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <View.VerticalProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/verticalRatingBar2"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
        android:layout_width="10dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:progressDrawable="@drawable/bluebar"
        android:progress="20" />
</LinearLayout>
```

- Why does it crash?
- How to draw scaling in middle of view? If i do this `getWidth()/2` then i get:

`10
9
8`

and i want all numbers centered.

Thank you in advance

EDIT: On left what i see in tablet 10.1" and right what i see in Eclipse. 9th scale line and `1` missing and `9` is draw near `10`

- what about drawing numbers in center? Or i have to do this manually getWidth()/2`-10`?

[image]
[image]

Comment: Post your logcat error trace.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I have simple custom view that should draw scaling numbers for
>   progressbar and when i add it to layout it causes crash of app.

You missed the constructor for the layout,

```
 public ScaleBar(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
```

Comment: Ok that helped :) but i have another problem... It doesn't draw as it should draw. Edited my question